# Handle submit event with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to handle a forms submit event with jQuery, but the following never triggers:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("hello");
        var p = document.createElement("input");

        // Add the new element to our form. 
        form.appendChild(p);
        p.name = "p";
        p.type = "hidden";
        p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

        // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
        password.value = "";

        // Finally submit the form. 
        $("#registerForm").submit();
    }
});
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: What's `$.validator`? a button? Could you please post this with HTML on [Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/) ?

Comment: It's a jQuery plugin called Validate - see http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/. As suggested, the HTML would help. I think submitHandler should be defined within the validate() method, but there could be other issues.

Comment: Your submit handler doesn't take the `form` parameter, and you try to reference it with `form.appendChild()`. You sure don't just have broken JS? Check your console.

Comment: Thanks. Found another error in my JS using the console. It works now.